# Laravel warning on penetration with owasp zap

Tags: php, laravel, penetration-testing

I have try scan my website (Laravel) with owasp-zap and i found alert "Cloud Metadata Potentially Exposed" and "Cookie No HttpOnly flag"

1. Cookie No Http Only Warning, i have try to changed "http_only" and "secure" to be true in config/session.php and i still get the warning
2. Cloud Metadata Potentially Exposed, what mean of this warning ?

==========

**I just resolve cookie no http only flag with adding function in app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken** :

```
protected function addCookieToResponse($request, $response)
    {
        $config = config('session');

        $response->headers->setCookie(
            new Cookie('XSRF-TOKEN',
                $request->session()->token(),
                $config['lifetime'],
                $config['path'],
                $config['domain'],
                $config['secure'],
                $config['http_only'])
        );

        return $response;
    }
```

Comment: The cookie could be referring to more than just the session cookie. Check which cookie specifically is mentioned. The 2nd one I do not know what that means but it is possible that the scanner tried a few default instance metadata endpoints for a few cloud services and found one that works. Check if there's more details about what it tried and try it yourself to see what data is actually exposed

Comment: if I look in more detail about the cookie in question, namely XSRF-Token, in developer mode XSRF-Token does not have the http only flag, while laravel session has it (if i set the http_only is true)

Comment: `XSRF-Token` is intended to be used by JS frameworks so it should not have an http_only flag. You can probably ignore that warning for this particular cookie (or if owasp allows it you might want to list it as not http only by design)

Answer (score 0):

### Cookie No HttpOnly Flag Warning:

The HttpOnly flag for cookies protects that the cookie cannot be accessed by client-side scripts, like JavaScript. This provides a level of protection against certain types of attacks, like cross-site scripting (XSS). If you've already set `'http_only' => true`, and `'secure' => true`, in `config/session.php`, then you're on the right way.

### Cloud Metadata Potentially Exposed:

This warning typically refers to the potential exposure of metadata endpoints that are associated with cloud services (e.g., AWS, GCP, Azure).

Cloud providers often expose an internal, unauthenticated endpoint that allows instances (like VMs) to query metadata about the instance itself (like IAM roles, instance ID, etc.). If an attacker can trick an application into making a request to this endpoint (for example, through SSRF - Server Side Request Forgery), they could potentially retrieve sensitive data. Check your application doesn't have open SSRF vulnerabilities that could be used to access these metadata endpoints.

Comment: **for cookie**, 
I rescan using owas zap, the warning is still there, referring to the XSRF-Token cookie, where the cookie does not have the http only attribute, whereas for the laravel session cookie it does (because I set http_only to true)
-
**cloud metadata potentially exposed**
my Laravel application is only for the frontend, where all applicable processes are sent to the backend (another application), so can I ignore alert or how can I resolve it?